# I need a formula to find the last xday of the month

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time

I am trying to write a formula to find the last Wednesday of each month of the year.  I also need the last Friday as well.  I am finding ways to get the first Wednesday of a month and tried to modify without success

Comment: Yeah? What are you currently using? What isn't it doing that it should?

Comment: I found a CHOOSE formula that would calculate the first Wednesday of the month by adding it to the previous month end date.  I tried modifying ad subtracting from the month end date but cannot get a consistent result.

Comment: Saturday, January 31, 2015 Friday, January 30, 2015
=A2-CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(A2,1),7,6,5,4,3,2,1)                             Sunday, May 31, 2015   Monday, May 25, 2015

Comment: Check out [how to ask a question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/886158/edit) yours

Comment: Please edit the formula and sample data into your question.

Answer (score 2):

If month is in B1 and year in B2, try for the last wednesday: `=DATE(B2;B1+1;1)-1-MOD(WEEKDAY(DATE(B2;B1+1;1)-1)+3;7)` and for the last friday: `=DATE(B2;B1+1;1)-1-MOD(WEEKDAY(DATE(B2;B1+1;1)-1)+1;7)`

Weekday gives you the day number of the week. `MOD`ing it with 7 gives the number of days that needs to be subtracted from the last day of the month. To find the last day of the month, I used `DATE` for the first of the next month (add 1 to month) and then subtract 1 day.

Comment: This works for me but you don't really need `MOD` function - you can use this formula for last Wed `=DATE(B2;B1+1;1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(B2;B1+1;1)-4)` - see my answer

Comment: Indeed. Your `WORKDAY.INTL` formula is more concise and better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

What's your input?

If you have any date in A2 this formula will find the last Wednesday of that month

`=EOMONTH(A2,0)+1-WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(A2,0)+1-4)`

Format result cell in required date format

change the 4 at the end for other days, 1 for Sunday through to 7 for Saturday

In Excel 2010 or later you can use `WORKDAY.INTL` function to get the same result, e.g.

`=WORKDAY.INTL(EOMONTH(A2,0)+1,-1,"1101111")`

Where "1101111" represents Wednesday, change the position of the 0 to get other days, e.g. Monday is "0111111", Tuesday is "1011111"

`EOMONTH+1` finds the first day of the following month then `WORKDAY.INTL` gives you the first Wednesday before that date, i.e. the last of the month

You can adapt these both to work with different inputs, e.g. if you have **month** and **year** then find the last Wednesday of that month with:

`=WORKDAY.INTL(DATE(year,month+1,1),-1,"1101111")`